# Pandas - why looping with str.extract is faster than one str.extractall

Tags: python, regex, pandas, series

I have a dataframe (~100k rows) with strings that I need to extract multiple items from and create new columns for.

Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import re

s = pd.Series(['param1=1&param2=&param3=ena&param4=n2oi3-284&',
            'param1=2&param2=2iot&param3=&param4=&',
            'param1=3&param2=afv&param3=39&param4=4obgg942n&',
            'param1=4&param2=&param3=1291&param4=0g2n48a&'])
```

I can use the regex `re.compile(r"=(.*?)&)"`with `str.extractall`, then unstack the resulting dataframe, select, and append the columns I want.

| match | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | NaN | ena | n2oi3-284 |
| 1 | 2 | 2iot | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 3 | afv | 39 | 4obgg942n |
| 3 | 4 | NaN | 1291 | 0g2n48a |

But when I tested it, it is slower than creating unique regexes in a dictionary for each parameter, e.g., `r"1=(.*?)&"`, then looping through that dictionary and using column assignment for each regex.

```
params = {'param1': re.compile(r"1=(.*?)&"),
        'param2': re.compile(r"2=(.*?)&"),
        'param3': re.compile(r"3=(.*?)&"),
        'param4': re.compile(r"4=(.*?)&")}

for k, rx in params.items():
    df[k] = s.str.extract(rx, expand=False)
```

When I used %%timeit, it appears that looping through the dictionary of regexes and creating a new column for each is quicker than using `str.extractall` (disregarding any sort of column assignment / resulting dataframe manipulation).

```
rx = re.compile(r"=(.*?)&")

%%timeit -n 100
s.str.extractall(rx)
```

2.56 ms ± 407 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%%timeit -n 100
for rx in params.values():
    s.str.extract(rx, expand=False)
```

791 µs ± 152 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Why is this? Am I incorrectly timing the functions / comparing different things? Shouldn't one pass over the column be quicker than iterating over the column 4 times?

Documentation for [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [str.extractall](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html#pandas.Series.str.extractall) doesn't say anything about this. Looking at the source code for [extractall](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.4/pandas/core/strings/accessor.py#L3127) versus [extract](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.4/pandas/core/strings/accessor.py#L2315), I can't identify why one is quicker than the other.

Thanks!

Comment: Strange. You seem to be right. (Although for me the times are faster and nearer: ~500ms vs. ~300ms)

Comment: The for loop should be faster since you are returning a series. For the faster option, kindly run it such that a new dataframe with a MultiIndex is created, to make it similar to extractall’s output, and see if the speed difference is still significant. Also, kindly share your pandas version

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but perhaps using a negated character class `([^&]*)&` can make it overall faster if you have that many rows, or if you don't want to cross newlines `([^&\n]*)&`

Comment: @sammywemmy I did have a prior version of pandas, updated to 1.3.4. The difference is lower, just over 1ms quicker now per loop. will try to add a multi-index to the test as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the source code `extractall` works with lists and appends to these which can be a slow if used frequently.

`extractall` tries to stay dynamic since it will capture all possible matches and therefore also iterates through the whole string, `extract` will return on the first match. If you only care about the first match you can also just use `extract` maybe like this:

```py
s.str.extract(re.compile(r"param1=(.*?)&*param2=(.*?)&*param3=(.*?)&*param4=(.*?)&"))
```

So maybe `extract` is better suited for your use case afterall?